# Customised Slider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, slider

I want a slider like this using flutt[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvdUw.png)er

Comment: Please add some code to what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

Use [syncfusion_flutter_gauges: ^20.3.47](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_gauges)

```
 Widget _getLinearGauge() {
    return Container(
      child: SfLinearGauge(
          minimum: 0.0,
          maximum: 100.0,
          orientation: LinearGaugeOrientation.horizontal,
          majorTickStyle: LinearTickStyle(length: 20),
          axisLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black),
          axisTrackStyle: LinearAxisTrackStyle(
              color: Colors.cyan,
              edgeStyle: LinearEdgeStyle.bothFlat,
              thickness: 15.0,
              borderColor: Colors.grey)),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    );
  }
```

[image]